# Plugin Reloader everytime i use custom plugin

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-plugins

Whenever I run my join csv script via custom plugin I have to run the plugin reloader for my script to take effect.

How can I make my script run without clicking plugin reloader everytime?

Heres my script:

```
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
import qgis
from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorJoinInfo
import csv

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
  # Change to your shapefile name
  if layer.name() == "Naguilian":
    qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
    shp = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
  # Change to your csv name
  if layer.name() == "naguiliandb":
    qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
    csv = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

# Set up join parameters
shpField='PIN'
csvField='u_pin'
joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
joinObject.joinLayerId = csv.id()
joinObject.joinFieldName = csvField
joinObject.targetFieldName = shpField
joinObject.memoryCache = True
shp.addJoin(joinObject)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using the **QtDesigner** and add a *QPushButton* to your plugin so that whenever the user clicks on this, the script is run.

Example:

We can add a push button to our plugin interface as shown below by dragging the button from the left panel to the *DockWidget*. We can then change the *Text* inside the button by double-clicking on it (e.g. `Run`) and also the *objectName* which is used in the code as an identifier (e.g. `runScript_button`).

[image: QtDesigner]

Now in your *main.py* file, we can define a function which runs your script when a user clicks on this button:

```
def run(self):
    def run_script():
        from PyQt4.QtCore import *
        import qgis
        from qgis.core import QgsMapLayerRegistry, QgsVectorJoinInfo
        import csv

        for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        # Change to your shapefile name
        if layer.name() == "Naguilian":
        qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        shp = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

        for layer in QgsMapLayerRegistry.instance().mapLayers().values():
        # Change to your csv name
        if layer.name() == "naguiliandb":
        qgis.utils.iface.setActiveLayer(layer)
        csv = qgis.utils.iface.activeLayer()

        # Set up join parameters
        shpField='PIN'
        csvField='u_pin'
        joinObject = QgsVectorJoinInfo()
        joinObject.joinLayerId = csv.id()
        joinObject.joinFieldName = csvField
        joinObject.targetFieldName = shpField
        joinObject.memoryCache = True
        shp.addJoin(joinObject)


    # Set up push button to connect to above function
    run_button = self.dlg.runScript_button
    run_button.clicked.connect(run_script)
```

Make sure to reload your plugin when you make changes to the user interface or code. Now when you click the button, it should run the script without you having to reload it everytime.

Comment: But I used plugin creator to create my plugin.. Sorry if my question is very basic.. Im really new to this.. :(

Comment: No need to apologise! When you created your plugin, you were given a choice of template between `dialog` and `dockwidget`. Which did you choose? Also, you can just put the code **inside** the `def run(self):` function.

Comment: I picked tool button with dialog sir Joseph.

Comment: In that case, replace `run_button = self.dockwidget.runScript_button` with `run_button = self.dlg.runScript_button`.

Comment: trying it now...

Comment: Having problems with indention sorry...

Comment: No problem, I tend to use the text editor [Sublime](https://www.sublimetext.com/) which helps me with the indentation :)

Comment: Finally able to run the script but the problem is when I click the new push button I created it wont Join. :(

Comment: Finally was able to run it correctly! :) Thank you sir Joseph! :)
My next question is how to remove the custom field name of fields? after I join database my field names became "naguilian_db_(fieldname)"

Comment: @ConradoDomingo - Glad you got it working :). Hmm from the [QgsVectorJoinInfo](https://qgis.org/api/structQgsVectorJoinInfo.html#a3a517ef5dd0d1ac77afd96ddb0e4c3c0), you could set a prefix by using something like `joinObject.prefix = ''`. Haven't used this so cannot confirm if it will work but the string should be empty otherwise it will use the default layer name.

Comment: thanks! @Joseph really appreciate your help. :) trying to learn from scratch. hehehe.

Comment: @ConradoDomingo - Most welcome, I am also still learning :)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to reload plugin with python code, simply do:

```
from qgis.utils import reloadPlugin

reloadPlugin('Plugin Name')
```

Somwhere in your code.

Comment: +1, good tip but I think the OP wants to avoid loading the plugin each time =)